# Problem with shortcut

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

Good evening, something super strange happens to me.
After starting my computer, when I press Ctrl + . I get this symbol e (letter e) and the cursor loses focus. I have checked the keyboard shortcuts, the custom ones and there is nothing.
I can't get rid of this odious problem and it's very annoying for example for vscode.
Any ideas? it would be greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance.

More info:

I use spanish layout.

I m on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1672408/linux-gnome-how-to-disable-ctrl-shortcut

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not find the post looking for it I really appreciate it, I was going crazy